# Kdenlive complains about missing dvdauthor app

Tags: 17.10, kdenlive

I'm running Kdenlive from the latest `Kdenlive-17.12.0d-x86_64.AppImage`. It all works fine except for that it complains about `dvdauthor` app every time I start it:

[image]

I'm not going to author DVDs (it's now 2018 after all), any idea how I can disable that?

Answer (score 0):

Install the package `dvdauthor` by running the following command

```
sudo apt install dvdauthor
```

Comment: Yes I got that, but my idea was exactly to avoid installing it.